# DomCrawler filterXPath for class with space in it

Tags: php, symfony, xpath

I am trying to use an filterXPath for Symphony Domcrawler to enumerate through the divs that look like this:

```
<div class="item item_other">
</div>
```

The code I am trying is:

```
$crawler->filterXPath( '//*[@class="item item_other"]' )->each( function ($node, $i)
{
  //whatever
}
```

Which returns zero results.  I have also tried class="item" and class="item_other".

What is the proper way to filter divs that have a class with a space in them?  I have been able to successfully do this with other div collections that have a single name for the class.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you pull the code out of Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools or the "real" page source? It might be some classes only get added after executing some JavaScript, which PHP's XPath implementation doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the fact that the divs were loaded by javascript.

Thank you Jens Erat.